# Mongo - exclude entries in one collection from another find()

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a local collection that logs when a user has viewed an entry. It stores the ID of the entry and the time it was viewed:

```
viewedDate = new Date();
notifications.insert({
  'viewed': this.data._id,
  'viewedDate': viewedDate
});
```

I want to exclude any of the 'viewed' ids in this collection from another find() (I basically want to count how many entries haven't been viewed)

How can I use the results of a notifications.find() to exclude results from another find()? If I assign the notifications.find() to a variable, it returns all kinds of stuff as an object.

### edit

OK, so if I use fetch() I can restrict what comes back - can I do something with this in a find()?

`myNotes = notifications.find({}, {fields: {'viewedDate' :0, _id:0}}).fetch();`

This returns

```
[
Object
    viewed: "HqYcCma3qKseHALyv"
    __proto__: Object
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some invaluable help from garilla_ in the Meteor IRC, I got it working, solution as follows:

```
myViewedOffers = notifications.find({},{fields: {'viewed':1}}).fetch();
myViewedArray = myViewedOffers.map(function(viewed){return viewed.viewed});
offerCount = Offers.find({_id: {$nin: myViewedArray}}).count();
```